# is there a way for conditional formatting to activate based on two conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an example table, say A1:F6.
I want to know if there's any conditional formatting approach that would allow me to look at each row which has data and highlight any cell that has a value of "0" to be highlighted as "RED"

Note I only want this conditional formatting to run for the rows which have data, eg >0

so far I have this but its not working for me
=if(And(A1:F1,>0,B1=0),)

Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help but possibly `=AND(A1>0,$B1=0)`

Comment: Define your rule over a range, then enter the formula with references for the top-left cell in that range (and $ wherever you don't want the cell to change). As the range progresses, cell refs in the formula will be moved accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @underscore_d suggested, you would need a combination of an anchored range to check the whole row for data, with a reference to the top corner of the range to check the individual cells e.g.

```
=AND(A2=0,COUNTIF($A2:$F2,"<>"&0))
```

[image]

or

```
=AND(A2=0,COUNTIFS($A2:$F2,"<>"&0,$A2:$F2,"<>"))
```

if you wanted to ignore rows that had a mixture of blanks and zeroes but no other numbers.

**EDIT**

If the blanks are coming from formulas so effectively you have ="" in some of the cells, you would need an array formula instead of Countifs either:

```
=AND(A2=0,SUM(($A2:$F2<>0)*ISNUMBER($A2:$F2)))
```

or

```
=AND(A2=0,SUM(($A2:$F2<>0)*($A2:$F2<>"")))
```

**EDIT 2**

One more suggestion - try and coerce the value (which may be a text) to a number. If it produces an error, take it as zero:

```
=AND(A2=0,SUM(IFERROR(VALUE($A2:$F2),0)))
```

There are are other ways of coercing to a number such as -- or 0+ but the intent of Value is probably clearer.

Comment: Tom I've gone with your second example and it looks to be the first step however the cells are still being highlighted in red even though there is no 'data' in them. I think this may be down to the fact the cells have formula's in them so are not registering as blank. I've been playing around with a combination of "ISNUMBER" for cells which have the formula in them but no text value, so the cell they are linked to is empty. And "COUNTIF <>0" for those cells which have a formula and have pulled a text value from another cell. Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Yes you are on the right lines! I don't think you can do this in a Countifs, so would have to use an array formula, either  =AND(A2=0,SUM(($A2:$F2<>0)*ISNUMBER($A2:$F2))) or =AND(A2=0,SUM(($A2:$F2<>0)*($A2:$F2<>"")))

Comment: Hi again Tom. I'm trying to get this to work and I think I've found what is holding it up. the ($AS:$F2<>0) section is still kicking out a "0" value even though some of the cells within the range have a positive result from the embedded formula. Meaning they should make the SUM not equal "0" but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: OK. Could you post a screenshot showing what you are getting and what you should be getting plz, and I'll see if I can reproduce it here?

Comment: Am going out now, but will have a look later. Maybe you have numbers formatted as text - possible using Value() might work.

Comment: Hi Tom. I've added a snapshot of the table where I want the conditional formatting to work. So if we take row 5 "B5:K5". If any cell within that range has a value from the corresponding formula I want any other cell within the range that doesn't have a value from the corresponding formula to be highlighted. Essentially showing the data set as incomplete. I've shown the formulas in the range just for reference.

Comment: Thanks, that shows me that G5 and H5 have text in them, but I must admit I'm struggling on this one as I don't know what's in the Weekend sheet which the fomulas refer to and I don't have an example of a row of data that possibly works and one that doesn't.